# Mysterious bash instances using a lot of CPU, how can I debug?

Tags: bash, process-management

I seem to have multiple `bash` processes running that are taking up most of my CPU. This is the output of `top -c`:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND         
20116 terdon    20   0 35288  14m  292 R 400.0  0.2   0:00.43 /bin/bash       
20106 terdon    20   0 35992  15m  280 R  95.9  0.2   0:00.65 /bin/bash       
20105 terdon    20   0     0    0    0 R  57.6  0.0   0:00.83 [bash]
```

This is the output of `ps aux | grep bash | head -3`:

```
terdon  7487 45.3  0.0      0     0 ?        R    19:31   0:01 [bash]
terdon  7488 66.0  0.0      0     0 ?        R    19:31   0:01 [bash]
terdon  7530 23.0  0.2  37984 17408 ?        R    19:31   0:00 /bin/bash
```

The PIDs change every time I run the command so it looks like something is constantly respawning `bash`.

Details:

- There are multiple `[bash]` entries. If I understand correctly `[process name]` means that the process was launched with no command line arguments.
- The PIDs change so something is spawning these.
- I have logged out and logged back in (I am working in Cinnamon) and the problem persists.

Now, I imagine this will go away if I restart, my main question is what can I use to track these processes down?

`top -c` does not help, `pgrep bash` just gives me different lists of PIDs, `lsof /bin/bash` just lists running bash instances and `pstree` shows them as independent processes.

In case it is relevant, I am running Linux Mint Debian, kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64, GNU bash, version 4.2.36(1)-release.

---

EDIT:

I have since rebooted (I had to) and, as expected, the problem has gone away. I am still interested in useful suggestions of how to track down such processes though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the output of `lsof | grep 'bash.*cwd'`. That will tell you the current working directories of the processes.

If you have `pstree`, take a look at its output. If not, take a look at the output of `ps aux -H`. That will tell you which processes own these mystery processes.

Start looking through configuration files for anything suspicious. Here's an incomplete list of ones you should check:

```
~/.bash*
~/.profile
/etc/profile
/etc/bash*
/etc/cron.*/*
```

The `[process name]` means that `ps` can't find that process' arguments, including argument 0 which contains the name of the file that was executed to create the process. That means `lsof /bin/bash` won't find these processes.

Comment: does <code> ps aux --forest</code> show anything weird under that bash session ?

Comment: @cesar remember to @ping me or I won't be notified of any comments. Unfortunately, I have restarted since I could no longer work so I can't test `--forest`. I am leaving the question open in hopes that I can do something if this occurs again.

Comment: Thanks, +1. The `cwd` is a good tip for next time.

Comment: @terdon np - thanks for alerting me to mention people.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at output of:

```
ps -p <pid> -o pid,user,tty,comm,args
```

Some shell scripts will appear as `/bin/bash` or `perl` in the output of `top` but `args` argument in the output of `ps` should give you the exact script running.