# Identifying suspicious bash process (high cpu and ram usage)

Tags: bash, shell, firefox, process-management

A couple of days ago I noticed a bash process in htop on my Arch system with relatively high, fluctuating cpu and ram usage. Started closing windows one by one to try pinpointing it, when I closed Firefox that also killed the process.

I then went online for answers, found this [pos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81639/mysterious-bash-instances-using-a-lot-of-cpu-how-can-i-debug/) and the second and third time I noticed it I tried some of the suggestions but I don't know how to interpret the output (posted below).

For reference, on the second and third sightings it had PID 6774 and 13054 respectively. Each time closing Firefox killed it. I noticed this over the course of two days.
[image]
[image]

It doesn't always start when I start Firefox. After login I filtered "bash" in htop and marked out the processes I could positively identify, then started Firefox but no new bash process started (at least not while I was looking) during a day of normal use.

Other info that may or may not be relevant:

- OS: archlinux-2023.04.01-x86_64
- dwm window manager, no other desktop environment
- login with startx, no other display manager
- I launch Firefox with dmenu

```
❯❯ ps 13054

    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  13054 ?        Sl     1:32 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox

❯❯ ps -p 6774 -o pid,user,tty,comm,args

    PID USER     TT       COMMAND         COMMAND
   6774 tim      ?        firefox         /usr/lib/firefox/firefox

❯❯ pstree

    systemd─┬─NetworkManager───3*[{NetworkManager}]
        ├─bash─┬─konsole─┬─bash───pstree13054
        │      │         └─3*[{konsole}]
        │      └─slstatus
        ├─bash───firefox─┬─Isolated Web Co───13*[{Isolated Web Co}]
        │                ├─3*[Isolated Web Co───14*[{Isolated Web Co}]]
        │                ├─Privileged Cont───13*[{Privileged Cont}]
        │                ├─RDD Process───3*[{RDD Process}]
        │                ├─Socket Process───4*[{Socket Process}]
        │                ├─Utility Process───3*[{Utility Process}]
        │                ├─2*[Web Content───12*[{Web Content}]]
        │                ├─Web Content───13*[{Web Content}]
        │                ├─WebExtensions───14*[{WebExtensions}]
        │                └─96*[{firefox}]
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─login───bash───startx───xinit─┬─Xorg─┬─xf86-video-inte
        │                               │      └─2*[{Xorg}]
        │                               └─dwm─┬─alacritty─┬─bash───ranger───mpv───9*[{mpv}]
        │                                     │           └─8*[{alacritty}]
        │                                     ├─alacritty─┬─bash───htop
        │                                     │           └─8*[{alacritty}]
        │                                     ├─2*[alacritty─┬─ranger]
        │                                     │              └─8*[{alacritty}]]
        │                                     ├─alacritty─┬─bash
        │                                     │           └─8*[{alacritty}]
        │                                     └─konsole─┬─bash
        │                                               └─3*[{konsole}]
        ├─mpv───15*[{mpv}]
        ├─polkitd───3*[{polkitd}]
        ├─rtkit-daemon───2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
        ├─sublime_text─┬─plugin_host-3.3───2*[{plugin_host-3.3}]
        │              ├─plugin_host-3.8───2*[{plugin_host-3.8}]
        │              └─15*[{sublime_text}]
        ├─sxiv
        ├─systemd─┬─(sd-pam)
        │         ├─at-spi-bus-laun─┬─dbus-daemon
        │         │                 └─4*[{at-spi-bus-laun}]
        │         ├─at-spi2-registr───3*[{at-spi2-registr}]
        │         ├─dbus-daemon
        │         ├─dconf-service───3*[{dconf-service}]
        │         ├─evolution-addre───6*[{evolution-addre}]
        │         ├─evolution-calen───7*[{evolution-calen}]
        │         ├─evolution-sourc───4*[{evolution-sourc}]
        │         ├─gvfs-udisks2-vo───4*[{gvfs-udisks2-vo}]
        │         ├─gvfsd─┬─gvfsd-dnssd───3*[{gvfsd-dnssd}]
        │         │       ├─gvfsd-network───4*[{gvfsd-network}]
        │         │       ├─gvfsd-trash───3*[{gvfsd-trash}]
        │         │       └─3*[{gvfsd}]
        │         ├─gvfsd-fuse───6*[{gvfsd-fuse}]
        │         ├─gvfsd-metadata───3*[{gvfsd-metadata}]
        │         └─pulseaudio─┬─gsettings-helpe───4*[{gsettings-helpe}]
        │                      └─2*[{pulseaudio}]
        ├─systemd-journal
        ├─systemd-logind
        ├─systemd-udevd
        └─udisksd───5*[{udisksd}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Other investigative tools include  `lsof -p <pid>` to see which files it has open, and if they keep changing use `strace -o mylogfile -p <pid>` to attach to the process and see what system calls it is making, if not in some sort of busy loop. You can pause the process with `kill -STOP <pid>`, and perhaps see if firefox complains after a while.

Comment: This looks like a Firefox parent process considering it has exactly the same RES, VIRT and SHR. No idea why it's using 100% of CPU though. Restart Firefox.

Comment: @meuh Thank you for the suggestions, I'll def. try them next time I catch it (I haven't noticed it the past two days). Do I need to run `strace` with `sudo`?

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov I did. It killed the process but it popped up again the next day. Haven't seen it since.

Comment: The Linux system can be configured to allow or forbid tracing in various
ways. The typical default will NOT allow strace to attach to a running
process. So you can either use `sudo strace -p ...`, or temporarily change
the kernel config with command `sudo sysctl kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0`,
then strace can attach to processes owned by the same user. Check first the old
value of the config with `sysctl kernel.yama.ptrace_scope` so you can restore it later. See `man 2 ptrace`.

Comment: I guess I'll just run it with `sudo` since it's more straightforward and I'm a noob. Thank you.